# Open the modal and touch two fingers to close the modal

Tags: android, react-native

On Android only, iOS normal behaviour
Open the modal and touch two fingers to close the modal
Swipe with two fingers or touch with two fingers to close the modal

I am guessing it is conflicting with gestures or overlapping navigation, does anyone know of a workaround for this?

```js
return (
    <Modalize
      ref={modalRef}
      HeaderComponent={renderHeader}
      flatListProps={{
        data: getDataSettingList(),
        renderItem: renderItem,
        keyExtractor: (item) => item.id,
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator: false
      }}
      modalStyle={{
        backgroundColor: '#212121'
      }}
      adjustToContentHeight={true}
    />
  );
```

I don't know the root cause